# Setting SimpleJdbcTemplate for Servlet

Tags: java, spring, servlets, jdbc, spring-jdbc

I am new to Spring and I am working on CAS. I need to query a database for user authentication but I am using a servlet as a controller. Therefore I need to know if there is any way to set up a SimpleJdbcTemplate in that servlet and use it to query the data base. If there is how to configure the web.xml file or any other file.

Thank you already.

Comment: why are you using servlets instead of java controllers?

Comment: If you are using jasig - CAS to validate your users, the authentication methods should be implemented in the CAS server. Your question is how to configure the database query auth. method in CAS server? Or are you trying to do anything else, like user authorization once the CAS server validate the user access?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not a good Idea to inject or access `JdbcTemplate` directly into a `Servlet` or a `Controller`.
You can have a `DAO` layer in between and inject your `JdbcTemplate` in you DAO would be a better approach.
In order to use a `JdbcTemplate` you need to have a `DataSource` defined somewhere in your configuration (Spring context either through xml or Annotations).
If you have a `UserDao`, then your spring configuration would be as follows

```
<bean class="com.xxx.dao.UserDAOImpl" id="userDAO">
   <property name="jdbcTemplate" ref="jdbcTemplate"/>
</bean>
<bean class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate" id="jdbcTemplate">
   <constructor-arg ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>
and here you need to difine your "dataSource" there are multiple ways to configure it, You may get better help from google.
```

And now, your `UserDaoImpl` looks a like

```
public class UserDAOImpl implements UserDAO {
   private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
   //setter and getter for jdbcTemplate

   public List<Map<String, Object>> getUsers() {
       String query = "select * from user";
       return jdbcTemplate.queryForList(query, new HashMap<String, String>());
   }
}
```

In your Servlet, you need to get the reference of this Dao using a `ServiceLocator`

in servlet class

```
...
public UserDAO getUserDao() {
   return ServiceLocator.getBean(UserDAO.class);
}
...
```

Again there are multiple ways to design the `ServiceLocator`, Here is the simple implementation.

```
public class ServiceLocator implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private static ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    /**
     * @return Returns the applicationContext.
     */
    public static ApplicationContext getApplicationContext() {
        return applicationContext;
    }

    public static <T> T getBean(Class<T> requiredType) throws BeansException {
        return getApplicationContext().getBean(requiredType);
    }

    /**
     * @param applicationContext The applicationContext to set.
     */
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        ServiceLocator.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

}
```

Finally, all these pieces are independent, You need to read upon individually, You will get much and precise help on google or Spring forums.